# Blender 3; CUDA errors, Cycles, Render, GPU Compute

Tags: cycles-render-engine, gpu

I have a project that was rendering in cycles GPU compute just fine but at some point went wonky and now GPU Compute always fails.  What steps can I take to get GPU compute working again?

I might be able to disable various layers and shaders until I find the culprit, but is there a better way then 'hunt and peck'?  I am not very satisfied with CPU render.

I have two Nvidia GTX 1070Ti SLI cards and generally GPU compute works fine, but I've done something in my project that is causing issues.  It was working with a 2048 tile size, and now that it's not working, even a tile size of 128 has the same issue.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Windows Event log shows that the Driver is crashing and restarting.  By exiting blender and restarting it and using 128 tile size, I was able to use GPU Compute.  While not the answer I was hoping for, I now know that the issue seems to be something with the display driver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a number of overlapping meshes/shaders as my project was very dirty.  After I cleaned up unwanted/unneeded meshes/shaders everything started working great again.  I think the take away is - keep my projects clean and crisp during development